# Ubuntu Studio Installer

Tags: software-installation

Im using Ubuntu Studio flavor right now and it works pretty well done. Yesterday I meet Nitrux OS which is based on debian and I would like to try it out.

The question is can I install ubuntu studio installer to add Ubuntu Studio’s benefits and programs on Nitrux since I do video and graphic content.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can make a dual-boot system. Or, since Nitrux is based on Debian, install those programs on your Ubuntu Studio install, or vice versa. You can also make your own OS with ´´´Cubic´´´ and add programs to you Ubuntu Studio iso.

Comment: Ubuntu Studio can also be installed on a pre-existing Ubuntu installation by installing the "ubuntustudio-desktop" package from Advanced Packaging Tool. Source https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Studio. So install Nitrux and then install the "ubuntustudio-desktop" package.

Comment: Note the Ubuntu Studio installer instructions; it fails to install on Linux Mint/Pop OS which are Ubuntu based; so I'd not trust you'll get it to run on a non-Ubuntu system

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: FYI:  Whilst off-topic here like your Nitrux OS, there are like features made available for Fedora by the same *developer(s)* of Ubuntu Studio (*Fedora Jam* I believe)